# How to force Android's text to speech out of the top speaker of the phone as if it were a regular phone call

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to simulate a phone call using Android's [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) services. I am trying to direct the speech to come out of the top speaker at your ear. This is done within a socket.io listener.

I have confirmed the `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` is using the Call output stream on my phone (Essential Phone), but it does not come out of the ear piece.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I don't have another device to test it on at the moment. Is that likely the issue?

```
private Emitter.Listener onEmergencyType = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String emergType = args[0].toString();

                    HashMap<String, String> myHashCall = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    myHashCall.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));

                    t1.speak(emergType, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashCall);

                    if(!t1.isSpeaking()) {
                        try {
                            GetAudio("emergencyType", emergType);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("PhoneCallActivity", "unexpected " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To route audio to the top speaker use AudioManager's method `setSpeakerphoneOn`. Set it to `false` to route sound to the top speaker, `true` -> to the bottom (loudspeaker)

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

Also, you will need extra permission in AndroidManifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Talking about earpiece - if it's wireless (Bluetooth) headset - you should also utilize `setBluetoothScoOn(true)/setBluetoothScoOn(false)` and `startBluetoothSco()/stopBluetoothScon()`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I had tried the ```audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);``` from other suggestions in other posts but the Android Manifest permission is what I was missing.